# Scala: Type mismatch required _$1 for lower context bound generics

Tags: scala, generics

I am having difficulty resolving this type mismatch compilation error

I have a series of Sources that I want to implement the strategy pattern to process the appropriate type

```
sealed trait Source
case class SourceA extends Source
case class SourceB extends Source
```

My preprocessor consists of a number of strategies that will process the appropriate case class

```
trait SourceStrategy[T <: Source] {    
    def isApplicable(source: Source): Boolean    
    def preprocess(source: T): Whatever
}
```

The idea is that a SourceStrategy implementation will exist for each case class above

I want to do something like this, whereby I loop through the appropriate strategies, find the one that is applicable and then invoke that one

```
class MyPreprocessor (strategies: Set[SourceStrategy[_ <: Source]]) {
  def performPreprocessing(source: Source) = {
    val preprocessor = strategies.filter(b => b.isApplicable(source)).head
    preprocessor.preprocess(source)
  }
}
```

I am getting a mismatch between `_$1` and `Source` in this last line.

I understand the reason that this occurs but I'm just not sure how to resolve it in a clean manner

Comment: Your problem is very similar to Scala's PartialFunction requirements with `apply` and `isDefinedAt`. Take a look at the implementation of Scala library and use the style: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.3/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala

Answer (score 1):

Either you want to check that a current strategy is applicable to a current source at compile time or you want to check this at runtime.

If you do at runtime then there is not much sense in making `SourceStrategy` generic

```
trait SourceStrategy {
  def isApplicable(source: Source): Boolean
  def preprocess(source: Source): Whatever
}
class MyPreprocessor (strategies: Set[SourceStrategy]) {
  def performPreprocessing(source: Source) = {
    val preprocessor = strategies.filter(b => b.isApplicable(source)).head
    preprocessor.preprocess(source)
  }
}
```

If you do at compile time then you can use heterogeneous collection and type class

```
trait PerformPreprocessing[L <: HList, T <: Source] {
  def performPreprocessing(strategies: L, source: T): Whatever
}
object PerformPreprocessing {
  implicit def recur[T <: Source, S, L <: HList, T1 <: Source](implicit
    performPreprocessing: PerformPreprocessing[L, T1]
  ): PerformPreprocessing[S :: L, T1] =
    (strategies, source) => performPreprocessing.performPreprocessing(strategies.tail, source)
  implicit def base[T <: Source, S <: SourceStrategy[T], L <: HList]: PerformPreprocessing[S :: L, T] =
    (strategies, source) => strategies.head.preprocess(source)
}

class MyPreprocessor[L <: HList](strategies: L) {
  def performPreprocessing[T <: Source](source: T)(implicit
    performPreprocessing: PerformPreprocessing[L, T]
  ): Whatever =
    performPreprocessing.performPreprocessing(strategies, source)
}
```

Comment: If I go with the runtime approach then I need to cast a Source to a SourceA within my strategy implementation which I wish to avoid

Comment: @DJ180 You can use pattern matching: `source match { case SourceA() => ...; case SourceB() => ... }`

Comment: @DJ180 Signature `trait SourceStrategy[T <: Source] { def isApplicable(source: Source): Boolean ... }` means that `strategyA.isApplicable` should be defined for all sources, not only `SourceA` but also `SourceB`.

Comment: That's why I had isApplicable accept a generic Source, so that it could accept any type.

Comment: @DJ180 You can do something at compile time or you can do something at runtime or you can persist some information from compile time (e.g. with `TypeTag`s) and use it at runtime but you can't use information from runtime at compile time, there is no time machine. You decide whether every specific element of `strategies` is applicable to this specific `source` at runtime. You can't use time machine and use this information at compile time to convince the compiler without casting.

Comment: Thanks, I'd be interested in seeing a solution involving `TypeTag`, I appreciate the solution above but seems complex

Comment: @DJ180 Solution with `TypeTag`s to what problem? As I already said `TypeTag`s can help to persist information from compile time to runtime. It seems you want to do something in reversed direction, namely deciding whether an element is applicable at runtime you want to convince the compiler at compile time. `TypeTag`s are irrelevant for that.

Comment: @DJ180 Monomorphic `SourceStrategy` (i.e `trait SourceStrategy {...`) is easier.